# can't create a image file from BASE64

Tags: java, android, image, base64

Well, i'm trying to send a picture from android to java, if i make it with compression it works really good, but i need to make it without compression beacuse i need a good or normal quality.
FixBitmap is my current Bitmap picture

```
//Android
FixBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
ConvertImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
Log.e(TAG,"LENGTH"+ConvertImage.length());
```

Length 43388

```
//Java
try{
String file=request.getParameter("image_data");
String filename=rt.getId()+"_"+rt.getName()+".png";
BufferedImage image = null;
byte[] imageByte;
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(file);
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
image = ImageIO.read(bis);
bis.close();
File outputfile = new File(filename);
ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);
Path destinationFile = Paths.get(getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"uploads\\", filename);
Files.write(destinationFile,imageByte);
}catch(Exception ex){
System.out.println("Error :"+ex.getMessage());
}
```

This code actually works as i said, but the compression make it looks in a very bad quality, so i tried to make it without compression, just converting my bitmap to a byte array, just like this

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(FixBitmap.getRowBytes() * 
FixBitmap.getHeight());
FixBitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
byteArray = buffer.array();
ConvertImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
Log.e(TAG,"LENGTH"+ConvertImage.length());
```

Length 252107

The code on my java side it's the same but now it doesn't work, it just shows me this error :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!

So I decided to print the length because maybe there is some restrictions about this...
so I hope you can help me with this (just send/get the picture without compression)

Comment: ImageIO.read() reads an image file, the kind of image file a user can have on their hard disk drive. Image files have a format, like PNG, JPEG, TIFF or whatever. "Without compression" is not a format. It won't do with ImageIO.read(). I don't know what is FixBitmap nor what is its strategy to compress to PNG, but PNG is supposed to be a lossless format, that is to say, it doesn't change any pixel of the image and therefore the quality is the same. It's possible that the image looks good on a phone, but not so good on superior display.